# Animated car.png as Marker Positions on PolyLine

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, animation, google-maps-api-3

I want to animate a car on google map.

This is javascript code for animating a circle.
Instead of this circle i want to animate a car.
please help!

```
 var lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 8,
    strokeColor: '#393'
  };

  // Create the polyline and add the symbol to it via the 'icons' property.
  line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: lineCoordinates,
    icons: [{
      icon: lineSymbol,
      offset: '100%'
    }],
    map: map
  });

  animateCircle();
}
```

Comment: See this [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/momom/1/edit).

Comment: The code in your question does *not* show how to animate a circle, but presumably the `animateCircle` function which you've not included does!

Comment: Port one of Mike Williams' "car trip" examples from the Google Maps Javascript API v2 to v3 [car trip](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip.htm), [car trip 2 (growing polyline)](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip2.htm), [car trip 3 (rotate car to face direction of travel)](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip3.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom Symbol marker (in your case, a car icon) using [SVG path notation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData), for example with Adobe Illustator or [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) and use that.

[Gold Star-sample from developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom)

```
  var goldStar = {
    path: 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z',
    fillColor: 'yellow',
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
    scale: 1,
    strokeColor: 'gold',
    strokeWeight: 14
  };

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: goldStar,
    map: map
  });
```